# Pushing images to docker registry using docker-client api

Tags: java, docker-registry, spotify-docker-client

While exploring docker-client api (java) what certificates are exactly required for setting up connection to the docker daemon running on a vm.

The code which I found online :

```
{
// Create a client based on DOCKER_HOST and DOCKER_CERT_PATH env vars
final DockerClient docker = DefaultDockerClient.fromEnv().build();

// Pull an image
docker.pull("busybox");

}
```

The link to above example is available at : https://github.com/spotify/docker-client

What I intend to do is access docker-daemon running on my master node(deployed through magnum api) and push my java applications docker-image onto the registry so that I can create pods on my cluster using these images.

I am not sure what more needs to be done as I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar, created images on a remote docker daemon and pushed it to a repository and further spawned containers. I used [docker-java](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java) client and it works fine. You might want to go through their wiki, the [issues](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/issues) page as usual proved to be very helpful for me.

**Basic Steps:**

1. Basically you need to create a `DockerClientConfig` which is
   something like:

   ```
   public DockerClientConfig dockerClientConfig() {
      return DefaultDockerClientConfig.createDefaultConfigBuilder()
          .withDockerHost("IP_where_docker_daemon_is_running_with_port")
          .withDockerTlsVerify("Transport_Layer_Security_accepts_Boolean")
          .withDockerCertPath("If_tls_is_true")
          .build();
   }
   ```
2. Then you need to create a `DockerClient`

   ```
   public DockerClient dockerClient() {
       DockerClient dockerClient = DockerClientBuilder.getInstance(dockerClientConfig())
           .withDockerCmdExecFactory(nettyDockerCmdExecFactory())
           .build();
       return dockerClient;
   }
   ```
3. Now you're ready to make calls to create Image, push Image,
   startContainer etc.

   ```
      File baseDir = new File(appImage.getSourceUri());

       BuildImageResultCallback callback = new BuildImageResultCallback(){
           @Override
           public void onNext(BuildResponseItem item){
               System.out.println("It's done - > " + item);
               super.onNext(item);
           }
       };

       PushImageResultCallback pushImageResultCallback = new PushImageResultCallback(){
           @Override
           public void onNext(PushResponseItem item){
               System.out.println("It's done too - >" + item);
               super.onNext(item);
           }
       };


       dockerClient.buildImageCmd(baseDir).withTag(appImage.getRegistryEndpoint()+"/apps/test:" + appImage
                              .getName()).exec(callback).awaitImageId();

       dockerClient.listImagesCmd().withShowAll(true).exec();

       AuthConfig authConfig = new AuthConfig().withUsername("admin").withPassword("admin")
                                               .withRegistryAddress("http://some_ip/v2/");

       dockerClient.pushImageCmd(appImage.getName())
                   .withAuthConfig(authConfig)
                   .withName(appImage
                   .getRegistryEndpoint()+ "/apps/test")
                   .withTag(appImage.getName())
                   .exec(pushImageResultCallback).awaitSuccess();

       CreateContainerResponse containerResponse = dockerClient.createContainerCmd(appImage
           .getRegistryEndpoint()+ "/apps/test:" + appImage.getName())
           .exec();

       dockerClient.startContainerCmd(containerResponse.getId()).exec();
   ```

That should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps that you could also simply use [Jib core APIs](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-core) which is a simple Java library that doesn't need any `docker` installed to build + push an image!

Read [this Google blog post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/introducing-jib-build-java-docker-images-better) to know more about it.